# How to call a static String method which returns string from main method?

Tags: java, static

In this below program, am passing a string value as argument to method print(String) which is static and returns string. Though I get no error,am not getting output.

```
public class StringTest {

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String  stw="iii";
        print(stw);
    }

    public static String print( String str )
    {
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you get? I dont see any issue with your code. even though you are calling the method for nothing.

Comment: Well, you are not printing your output

Comment: please don't down vote. this person tried something at least. Is there any standard on stack-overflow that is put as mandatory knowledge level  before posting a question ?

Comment: @NamdanAthreya FYI, in the MarkDown syntax used by this StackOverflow site, use four spaces instead of a TAB in your source code sample. I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't getting any output because you aren't actually printing anything. If you want to print something, you'll have to interact with the program's stdout or stderr. E.g.:

```
public static void print(String str) {
    System.out.print(str);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the body of print method.

```
public static void print(String str)
{
  System.out.println(str);
}
```

You are returning a string value and didn't do anything with it. Send it to [`println`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.String-) method to print the string by outputting to the [console](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console_application).

Comment: Also change return type to `void`.

Comment: edited my answer, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks ok, and you are getting the string in the return of the **print** method, but since you are not printing it at all is getting lost...

This statement here:

```
print(stw);
```

must be replace with somehthing like:

```
System.out.println(print(stw));
```